# Menu highlight custom post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I am a WP beginner and hope if anyone can help me out.

I have recently installed **WP 3.3.2** and **Jigoshop 1.2** to see how things works if I can use WP as an ecommerce website.

The problem I am facing at the moment is in order to display the products, Jigoshop creates a page in WP, as when you click on the page the link will get redirect from `?page_id=5` to `?post_type=product`. As the page being redirected the current_page_item class doesn't stay/appear to show the style for current position in the menu.

The current menu code is `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>`

Many thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Jigoshop are doing it wrong...

Instead of adding a page to the menu, you can add a link, directly to your 'product' archive page.

You *could*, just add a custom link that points to the archive page, though - this has its drawbacks... notably if the url ever changes you'll have to manually update it and it will also not stay 'current' when you view individual post of that post type.

To get round this I've created [this very small plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-type-archive-links/). It adds an extra metabox to your Appearance > Menu page, which lists your (archived) post types. You can use this to add the product archive link to your menu.

Comment: +1 (also on the plugin page) Don't know how I could live without it. :)